# protocol buffer build.sh error and show "protobuf test program failed to link"

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am setting up protocal buffer in my mac(10.14.4)
I step by step according to the readme
When I input `./scripts/build.sh` in the terminal and it tells me:

```
ERROR:
protobuf test program failed to link:
perhaps you need to add -Llibdir to your LDFLAGS.
```

what should I do?
what is mean `add -Llibdir to your LDFLAGS` and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you share what guide you are following to setup protocal buffer?

Comment: github alexeyxo/protobuf-swift